# response 405 from Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to scrape the authors data from http://quotes.toscrape.com/, but unfortunatly the author pages return 405 when I run the spider; whereas in the browser or by fetching the url in `Scrapy shell` it returns `200`.

```py
class AuthorsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'authors'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 50,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.1,
        'FEED_URI': f'output/authors_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}.csv',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {'csv': 'scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter'},
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
        'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ('name','birth_date','birth_location','description',) 
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for _ in response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            author_page = response.xpath("//a[text()='(about)']/@href").get()
            yield response.follow(author_page,
                                method="GET",
                                callback=self.parse_author)

        next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)


    def parse_author(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.xpath("//h3[@class='author-title']/text()").get(),
            'birth_date': response.xpath("//span[@class='author-born-date']/text()").get(),
            'birth_location': response.xpath("//span[@class='author-born-location']/text()").get(),
            'description': response.xpath("//div[@class='author-description']/text()").get()
        }
```

here is part of the response when I run `scrapy crawl authors`:

```py
2023-01-02 10:53:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/10/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/9/)
2023-01-02 10:53:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (405) <NONE http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Suzanne-Collins/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/7/)
2023-01-02 10:53:34 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <405 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Suzanne-Collins/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2023-01-02 10:53:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (405) <NONE http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/W-C-Fields/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/8/)
2023-01-02 10:53:34 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (308) to <NONE http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/John-Lennon/> from <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/John-Lennon>
2023-01-02 10:53:34 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <405 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/W-C-Fields/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2023-01-02 10:53:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (405) <NONE http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Alfred-Tennyson/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/8/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with
response.follow() you are asking **parse** function to follow this url again.
if you want to pass url to another function then you need to use Scrapy.Request() instead of response.follow().
if you want to pass author's page urls to **parse_author** then your code should look like this .

```
class AuthorsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'authors'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 50,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.1,
        'FEED_URI': f'output/authors_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}.csv',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {'csv': 'scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter'},
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
        'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ('name','birth_date','birth_location','description',) 
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for _ in response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            author_page = response.xpath("//a[text()='(about)']/@href").get()
            yield scrapy.Request(author_page,
                                method="GET",
                                callback=self.parse_author)

        next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)


    def parse_author(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.xpath("//h3[@class='author-title']/text()").get(),
            'birth_date': response.xpath("//span[@class='author-born-date']/text()").get(),
            'birth_location': response.xpath("//span[@class='author-born-location']/text()").get(),
            'description': response.xpath("//div[@class='author-description']/text()").get()
        }
```

attached image [image: screenshot]
if you still have any question please reply to this answer.
Happy learning!.

Comment: As I use the code you provided, I encounter the `raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')` error. So I change `author_page` to `response.urljoin(author_page)` in my `Request` arguments; the spider runs without any errors, but the `405` response problem persists.

Comment: It is running on my side. You can see in the attached image.

Comment: Also pls change from **Scrapy.Request**  to **scrapy.Request**

Comment: Is it possible that there might be a problem with my network connection or IP address?

Comment: I don't think so. If there were any such issue then you can't visit that page on your browser as well. Try to investigate that author page url in scrapy shell.

Comment: Try this `author_page = response.urljoin(author_page)` to get rid of that error. The error, however, is because of the relative urls.

Comment: THANKS! I was able to solve the problem by adding a '/' at the end of the `urljoin` like `response.urljoin(author)+'/'`. It was indeed a url issue.